# Swift 3 / Xcode 8 - CNContact [access] <Private>

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, cncontactstore

My code crashes as soon as it tries to request access to the `CNContactStore`. Any ideas if this is a **beta** issue?

```
var addressBookStore = CNContactStore()

addressBookStore.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { (granted, error)
```

in

// This console message is triggered at the crash - Messenger[836:1175155] [access] private

the crash occurs at this line and even preventing even printing the error!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As suggested here : https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts

> **Important**
>
> An iOS app linked on or after iOS 10.0 must include in its Info.plist
>   file the usage description keys for the types of data it needs to
>   access or it will crash. To access Contacts data specifically, it must
>   include NSContactsUsageDescription.

You have to addd NSContactsUsageDescription key in your Info.plist file

[image]

Then you will get authorization dialog. Without this key app will crash.

[image]

```
let addressBookStore = CNContactStore()

addressBookStore.requestAccess(for: CNEntityType.contacts) { (isGranted, error) in
    print(isGranted)
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: such a simple solution. I cant believe i missed that! thanks a lot